# Allow non-admin users to access AWS Resource created by root user

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

I have created few API Gateway resources as `root` user in AWS. When I use my personal user (part of `Admin` group with full admin access) to access these from console, the list is empty. But when I use my API access keys in CLI, I can see and access them. This issue exists for all services including `s3`, `acm` etc. Please help me with a way to add `admin` group in access list or owners.
Thanks in advance.

[image: AWS API Gateway resource list]

Adding policy simulator SS:
[image: AWS Policy Simulator SS]

Comment: Is the region same in cli and console?

Comment: Can the user perform any actions? Is it only listing that is not working? Does the admin group have the official AWS policy? Are there any IAM permission boundaries?

Comment: Double check that the region selector and the AWS account is the same. The fact that the root user created certain resources does not prevent other users from accessing it

Comment: @Marcin yes. I use only. 'us-east-1'.

Comment: @TamásSallai AWS account also the same.

Comment: @ChrisWilliams
1. Able to perform other actions as well.
2. Since not able to list in console, unable to perform any other actions as well.
3. Checking
4. ```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```